# Removing black background in ENVI

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, envi, srtm, aster

I am trying to compare two DEM products ASTER and SRTM v.3, but the ASTER has the black background which i think will interfere with my analysis. I don't have access to ArcGIS where I can do this easily, I am only working with ENVI 5.2

Comment: Data Ignore Value as mentioned above is the only option that I know and used so far

Comment: What background values are in the ASTER and SRTM data within the "black background"?

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell me what module are you using ?

You should be able to do that. You need to use the "Edit ENVI Header" and then open the Edit Attributes. When you are there scroll down to "Data Ignore Value" and set to Zero.

Comment: I am using ENVI classic. That may be a problem considering that some pixels in my actual data have elevations of zero and less

Comment: If you are a beginner with the ENVI , They have a list of tutorial that may help you to speed things up. http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Learn/Resources/Tutorials.aspx I dont have my ENVI on my computer now but I have used it in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You can open "Edit header" --> "Edit Atrributes" --> "Data Ignore Value", and then set the background value.

Comment: Had already tried that. But it seems to still interfer with the stats (min, max and mean) of the image.

Comment: For that, you can use the mask band to mask the nodata values when you use "Compute Statistics".